# Is it possible to change grid system dimension for vue?

Tags: vue.js, grid, vuetify.js

Vue uses 12-grid system. Is it possible to change the dimension for any other amount of grids?

Answer (score 1):

There is a sass variable called `$grid-columns` which is set by default to 12.

You can modify it to change vuetify grid system to any other number of columns.

Read more about vuetify variables [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables/#variable-api).